# Error "ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)" with Python 2.7.13 and Keras 2.0.8

Tags: python, keras

I get the *ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)* above when trying to load a previously saved Keras model (I think it's a Python error though that has nothing to do with Keras, but not quite sure.)

```
from keras.models import load_model
from keras import __version__ as keras_version
model = load_model("model.h5")
```

I searched on Google but didn't find a working solution. I tried deleting pya-files with: `sudo find /usr -name '*.pyc' -delete` but that didn't help either.

Do you have an idea how I can fix this error? Thank you!

Comment: Do you have the model that generated the file working on another python version/environment?? You could try to save the model as JSON from there, and save the weights with numpy (probably not allowing pickle), and then try in your python version.

Answer (score 1):

I know the post is a bit older, but I just ran into the same problem.

As @Daniel Möller said, it was because I had installed different versions of Python, Tensorflow and Keras. Try to train the model again, in the same environment that you use to load the model afterwards. Or at least make sure that the Python version and the modules used are installed in the same version.